# Can't display dynamic content with Ajax in my rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am currently doing a simple to do app and I am trying to implement ajax when creating a new task. I am trying to render a partial will contain the new task's information and then append it to an already existing table, but I keep getting the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/projects/4/tasks 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my task create form

```
# app/view/tasks/_create_task.html.erb
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <%=form_for [@project, @task], remote: true do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%=f.label :task_name %>
            <%=f.text_field :task_name, class: "form-control"%>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%=f.label :deadline %>
            <%=date_select :task, :deadline, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <%=f.submit "Create task", class: 'btn btn-info' %>
        <%end%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my controller code for the task create action

```
    #app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
    before_action :set_project

    def create
    @task = @project.tasks.build(set_params).save

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html do 
        if @task.valid?
          flash[:notice] = "Your task has been successfully saved"
          redirect_to project_path(@project)
        else
          render 'projects/show'
        end
      end 

      format.js 
    end
   end
   private
   def set_params
    params.require(:task).permit!
   end

   def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   end
```

and the corresponding create.js.erb template

```
#app/view/tasks/create.js.erb
$('#task-table').append("<%= j render 'task', task: @task, project: @project%>");
```

and finally the partial that I am trying to render:

```
#app/views/tasks/_task

<% if task.erased %>
  <% row_class = 'hidden'%>
<% end %>

<% if task.erased == nil && task.checked %>
  <% row_class = 'row-disabled success' %>
  <% icon_class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-icon' %>
<%elsif task.erased == nil && task.checked == nil %>
  <% row_class = '' %>
  <% icon_class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked check-icon ' %>
<% end %>

<tr class = "<%= row_class  %>" id = 'task-row' >
  <td>
    <%= link_to project_check_task_path(project, task, checked: true), method: 'patch' do %>
      <span class= "<%=icon_class  %>"></span>
    <% end %>
  </td>
  <td><%= task.task_name %></td>
  <td><%= task.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")%></td>
  <td><%= task.deadline.strftime("%b %d, %Y")%></td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to project_erase_task_path(project, task, erase: true), method: 'patch' do  %>
        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

NOTE: Instead of rendering the partial I'have tried to append any dynamic content such as @task.title etc, and all throwing the same error.

Thanks for your help.!

Comment: First issue I've noticed is that you need to permit the task attributes too (task_name, ...)

Comment: Have you looked at the application logs to see if there are some additional infos?

Comment: Provide full log of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have might be from the following line:

```
@task = @project.tasks.build(set_params).save
```

Because `@project.tasks.build(set_params).save` returns either `true` or `false`, while you are treating it as your task object.

It should be:

```
@task = @project.tasks.build(set_params)
@task.save
```

or

```
@task = @project.tasks.create(set_params)
```